# Need help optimizing query that is taking >28 seconds and eating cpu

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation with a large amount of entries (posts) in the table.

I have the following query that is taking almost 30 seconds. Any ideas on how I can optimize?

I think that the cast is what is stalling here but not sure.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count_7_day_total'
AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'post_views_count_7_day_last_date'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '1626290358' ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: try DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY and add indexes

Comment: Add useful indexes via:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/